# Can not set path variable in mac for KobWeb

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I can't set path variable for kobweb framework in mac according to kobweb github readme https://github.com/varabyte/kobweb. Here is the screen short I have attached step by step I was trying to setup

[image: Trying set path variable using bash_profile]

[[image: Set path variable][2]]

[image: Creating kobweb project but command not working]

Answer (score 3):

You need to source your profile after creating it -- `source ~/.bash_profile` for example. Does that help?

Also, what happens if you type `~/Applications/kobweb-0.9.0/bin/kobweb` ? Just to make sure everything downloaded and extracted correctly.

Read more about `source` here: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/source-command

Also, when you open a new terminal, it may load `~/.bashrc` and not `~/.bash_profile`, so you can either move the `PATH` setting in there *or* load the `~/.bash_profile` file directly in your `~/.bashrc` file, see also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316033

Comment: $ brew install varabyte/tap/kobweb

the command is working now according to the documentation thanks @Davide Herman

Comment: And not just homebrew! A growing list of install options are being documented here: https://github.com/varabyte/kobweb#install-the-kobweb-binary